# How to test $http service in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing

Below my code
I created small MEAN application. I don't know how to test service. please help me

### Application Code

```
var app = angular.module('guestPhoneBook',[]);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider,$compileProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol("{[{");
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol("}]}");
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
});

app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.company = "IGATE";
});

app.directive('guestDir',function(){
    return function($scope, GuestDatas, $http){

            var refresh = function(){
                var promise = GuestDatas.getAllGuest();
                promise.success(function(data){
                    $scope.guestList = data;
                    $scope.newContact ="";
                });
            }
            refresh();

            $scope.addNewContact = function(){
                promise = GuestDatas.addNewGuest($scope.newContact);
                promise.success(function(){
                    refresh();
                });

            }

            $scope.deleteGuest = function(id){
                promise = GuestDatas.deleteGuest(id);
                promise.success(function(data){
                    refresh();
                });
            }
            $scope.edit = function(id){
                promise = GuestDatas.editGuest(id);
                promise.success(function(data){
                    $scope.updateShow = true;
                    $scope.newContact = data;
                });
            };

            $scope.updateGuestData = function(){
                //console.log($scope.newContact);
                promise = GuestDatas.updateGuest($scope.newContact);
                promise.success(function(data){
                    refresh();
                });
            }
        }
});

/*
app.service('AddService',function(){
    this.add = function(a,b){
        return a+b;
    }
});
*/      
app.controller('guestCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.updateShow = false;
    //$scope.addResult = AddService.add(5,6);
});

app.factory("GuestDatas",function($http){
    return {
        getAllGuest : function(){
            var url = '/guestDetails';
            return $http.get(url);
        },
        addNewGuest:function(newGuest){
            var url = '/guestDetails';
            return $http.post(url,newGuest);
        },
        deleteGuest:function(id){
            var url ='/guestDetails/'+id;
            return $http.delete(url);
        },
        editGuest:function(id){
            var url='/guestDetails/'+id;
            $http.put(url);
        },
        updateGuest:function(guestData,fn){
            console.log(guestData);
            var url = "/guestDetails/"+guestData._id;
            $http.put(url,guestData);
        }
    }
});
```

### Test file:

```
describe("Testing app.js", function() {
    var myController;
    var scope;
    var rootScope,httpBackend,factory;

    beforeEach(module('guestPhoneBook'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope,GuestDatas,$http,$httpBackend){
        rootScope = $rootScope;
        scope = rootScope.$new();
        myController = $controller('guestCtrl',{$scope:scope});
        factory = GuestDatas;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    }));

    it('should have controller named guestCtrl',function(){
        expect(myController).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have updateShow object and attached to scope',function(){
        expect(scope.updateShow).toBeDefined();
        expect(scope.updateShow).toBeFalsy();
    });
    it("API method to be defined",function(){
        expect(factory.getAllGuest).toBeDefined();
        expect(factory.addNewGuest).toBeDefined();
        expect(factory.deleteGuest).toBeDefined();
        expect(factory.editGuest).toBeDefined();
        expect(factory.updateGuest).toBeDefined();
    });
    it("API method to be function",function(){
        expect(factory.getAllGuest).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
        expect(factory.addNewGuest).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
        expect(factory.deleteGuest).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
        expect(factory.editGuest).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
        expect(factory.updateGuest).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
        //factory.getAllGuest(fn);
    });
    it("testing http call", function(){
        httpBackend.when('GET', '/guestDetails').respond(200,{});
        expect(httpBackend.flush).not.toThrow();
        //httpBackend.expect('GET', '/guestDetails').respond(1200);
    });
});
```

Please help me to test the service inside my directive.
In my test file. I kept local j_son data and tried to test but still am not getting proper response.

Thanks in advances dear friends..
AK..

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: this is my directive :  
app.directive('guestDir',function(){
 return function($scope, GuestDatas, $http){
   
   var refresh = function(){
    var promise = GuestDatas.getAllGuest();
    promise.success(function(data){
     $scope.guestList = data;
     $scope.newContact ="";
    });
   }
   refresh();
});

this is my factory:
app.factory("GuestDatas",function($http){
 return {
  getAllGuest : function(){
   var url = '/guestDetails';
   return $http.get(url);
  },
  }});
Refresh fn will return all guest data in my data base. can you please help me to test this service.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question seems to broad to me. You should limit your question to what specifically you want to test. Your service and directive should be tested separately. The developer guides are helpful. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mocked service `$httpBackend` to test `$http` in Jasmine

Comment: yes i tried .. still i was struggling.. can you please tel me how to test link function in directive.